# Match EventLog and SearchResultEntry

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I want to get all ad changes, including all attributes, who made the change and on which machine. No api satisfies both conditions, so I use a combination of [SearchResultEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchresultentry) and [EventLogRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord).

To get the "who" and "where" I register a `EventLogWatcher`:

```
        var query = new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, "*");
        var propertySelector = new EventLogPropertySelector(new[]
        {
           "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetUserName']",
           "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetDomainName']",
           "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TargetSid']",
           "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']",
           "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectDomainName']",
           "Event/EventData/Data[@Name='SubjectUserSid']",
           "/Event/EventData/Data[@Name='AttributeLDAPDisplayName']",
           "/Event/EventData/Data[@Name='AttributeValue']",
           "/Event/EventData/Data[@Name='OperationType']",
           "/Event/System/Computer"
        });

        using (var watcher = new EventLogWatcher(query))
        {
            watcher.EventRecordWritten +=
                (object eventLogWatcher, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        var eventLogRecord = eventArgs.EventRecord as EventLogRecord;
                        var props = eventLogRecord.GetPropertyValues(propertySelector);
                        // process entry
                    };
            watcher.Enabled = true;
            // block the thread like await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
```

But this will not include all changes and keep in mind, that the properties will vary based on the event type. To get a full copy of the new object when a change occurs, you can register a callback with `SearchRequest`:

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(dn,filter,scope,attributes);

request.Controls.Add(new DirectoryNotificationControl());

IAsyncResult result = _connection.BeginSendRequest(
    request,
    TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    PartialResultProcessing.ReturnPartialResultsAndNotifyCallback,
    (res) =>
    {
        var r = _connection.GetPartialResults(res);
        foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in r)
        {
          // process entry
        }
    },
    request);
```

But how do I match these two events ? [SearchResultEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchresultentry) contains just a new object with attributes and [EventLogRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogrecord) many information, but none to match them exactly. It is assumed, that both tools run on the same domain controller. Just time as match property is not sufficient enough.

Comment: ad sux, im sorry mate

Comment: As a person who develops the product which does exactly the same thing I can tell that this is a very complicated solution. A ton of research and development must be made to make it work, and you will face with many difficulties, such as site replication, deleted objects, etc. Moreover, directory notification works perfectly if you make one single change. Try to create 10000 users with a script and see what notifications you’ll get. The easiest way to accomplish this is not to match changes with events, but generate changes from events.

Comment: Starting from Windows Server 2008 there is a special audit category called Directory Service Changes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-directory-service-changes. Enable it and collect events from all DCs in domain

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I rather pull or receive push messages with EventLogWatcher ?

Comment: I use the following rule: pull when you deal with large amount of data, otherwise push. In your case there may be millions of events, so pull method should be used

Answer (score 0):

You can use pull mush method to millions of data.You don't need to get all the events from AD intead 5136 event itself has all the changes in AD.You can get all the information from `EventLogRecord` API.Below are my codes

```
    public class EventLogMgmt{   
    public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            Stirng logName = "Security";
            String queryString = "<QueryList>  <Query Id="0" Path="Security"><Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID = 5136)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>";
     EventLogQuery subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery(logName, PathType.LogName, queryString);
                    watcher = new EventLogWatcher(subscriptionQuery, null, true); //EventLog watcher                  
                    watcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(EventLogEventRead);
                    watcher.Enabled = true;                
        }

         public void EventLogEventRead(object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
            {
                if (arg.EventRecord != null)
                {
                    EventRecord eventInstance = arg.EventRecord;
                    //String eventMessage = eventInstance.FormatDescription(); // You can get event information from FormatDescription API itself.
                    //String eventMessageXMLFmt = eventInstance.ToXml(); // Getting event information in xml format
        String[] xPathRefs = new String[9];
        xPathRefs[0] = "Event/System/TimeCreated/@SystemTime";
        xPathRefs[1] = "Event/System/Computer";
        xPathRefs[2] = "Event/EventData/Data[@Name=\"TargetUserName\"]";
        IEnumerable<String> xPathEnum = xPathRefs;
        EventLogPropertySelector logPropertyContext = new EventLogPropertySelector(xPathEnum);
        IList<object> logEventProps = ((EventLogRecord)arg.EventRecord).GetPropertyValues(logPropertyContext);
        Log("Time: ", logEventProps[0]);
        Log("Computer: ", logEventProps[1]);
                }
            }
    }
```

All the information like target user,caller user name,modified properties,etc available in above API.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this solution was already mentioned by @oldovets. And xml is very bulky, I would recommend to select properties with  EventLogPropertySelector

Comment: Thank you, but for now I'll consider @oldovet's comment as answer